# Android JAVA - Service return OutOfMemoryError exception after some while

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, threadpool

I am developing my first android app. I have been created a Service class which role is to check if any new information on an external webpage. The HTTP request and service work as i should, but after a while I get these `OutOfMemoryError`.

Are someone able to see where the Service gather all that memory?

**Error message 1.**

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (stack size 16384 bytes) failed: Try again
at java.lang.VMThread.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1029)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool.enableConnectionGC(AbstractConnPool.java:140)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.createConnectionPool(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:120)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:98)
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.(AsyncHttpClient.java:210)
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.(AsyncHttpClient.java:149)
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.(AsyncHttpClient.java:119)
at com.quickit.app.MyService.checkUpdates(MyService.java:89)
at com.quickit.app.MyService.access$1(MyService.java:75)
at com.quickit.app.MyService$TimeDisplayTimerTask$1.run(MyService.java:68)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Error message 2.**

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: thread creation failed
at java.lang.VMThread.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1050)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:913)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1295)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:81)
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.sendRequest(AsyncHttpClient.java:893)
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.post(AsyncHttpClient.java:688)
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.post(AsyncHttpClient.java:671)
at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.post(AsyncHttpClient.java:658)
at com.quickit.app.MyService.checkUpdates(MyService.java:90)
at com.quickit.app.MyService.access$1(MyService.java:75)
at com.quickit.app.MyService$TimeDisplayTimerTask$1.run(MyService.java:68)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5092)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**My service class.**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    boolean login = false;
    // constant
    public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds
    String address = Utilities.getAPIUrl();
    // run on another Thread to avoid crash
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    // timer handling
    private Timer mTimer = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.quickit.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       login = prefs.getBoolean("login", false);

        // cancel if already existed
        if(mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
        } else {
            // recreate new
            mTimer = new Timer();
        }
        // schedule task
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
    }

    public class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override

            public void run() {
                // run on another thread
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(login) {
                            checkUpdates();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

private void checkUpdates() {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.quickit.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String from_id =  prefs.getInt("user", 0)+"";
        final String lastCheck =  prefs.getString("last_check", "0");

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("type", "get_ask_questions");
        params.put("fromid", from_id);
        params.put("last_check", lastCheck);

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.post(address, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
                try {
                        notification(response);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is constantly creating a new AsyncHttpClient object every time that timer expires! If the object never finishes its work, at some point, you will run out of memory.

Since you are just periodically checking for updates, you should make the AsyncHttpClient object static and just reuse it.

Look at http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ specifically, the Recommended Usage section.

Comment: Think this will solve the problem. I will try implement the static accessors and see how the app will handle the memory now. Thx @iheanyi

Comment: This may be a dummy question but why are AsyncHttpClient object not take care of by the Java garbage collection, when the methoed is finish?

Comment: @boje - So, AsyncHttpClient creates an object which runs its own threads. This allows it to operate asynchronously - it runs even while your code is busy doing something else. If you wanted something that only has local lifetime, use HttpClient instead. So, given that it goes off and runs on it's own, you need to explicitly tell it to close or stop running when you are done with it. Since you don't do that and the AsyncHttpClient thread is still running, the garbage collector has no reason to free up the memory.

Comment: @boje Remember, just because the call to post() returned, doesn't mean the post() operation has actually finished (it's an AsyncHttpClient after all). So, as the user, you need to explicitly close down the AsyncHttpClient object if you want that memory freed. Note, since it works in the background and you're using a static instance, you should only call close() in a method that gets called when you're terminating the service. If you want to close() before that, you should either check that any pending operations are finished or close() understanding that pending operations may not complete.